# Fabric.js - How to select a specific object by type

Tags: object, canvas, fabricjs, getelementbyid

I'm trying to figure out how to grab a fabric object and change its properties when its moving. I have three different shapes. A fabric.Rect, fabric.Circle and fabric.Triangle. They all have different property values so if anyone knows how to change them accordingly that would be greatly appreciated.

This is how I tried doing it with no success.

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
  var activeObject = e.target;
  activeObject.shadow = null;


   if (e.target = fabric.Rect){
    activeObject.height = 40;
    activeObject.width = 40;
    };

    if (e.target = fabric.Circle){
     activeObject.radius = 20; 
     };

    if (e.target = fabric.Triangle){
     activeObject.height = 40;
     activeObject.width = 35 
     };


});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function onObjectSelected(e) {
  console.log(e.target.get('type'));
}
canvas.on('object:selected', onObjectSelected);
```

Comment: I see what you did. Unfortunately, I have to have the event listener "object:moving." This is because I have a clone of the selected object. So instead could I not do this:

`canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {

      var activeObject = e.target;
      var name = e.target.get('type');
      activeObject.shadow = null;
     
        if (name = circle{
         circle.radius = 20;
        };
        
    });`

Comment: yes, its fine. As long as you got what you want its good! Main was to get your object, that i was trying to convey you. [e.target.get('type')]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I am running into a RefferenceError as circle is not defined. Apparently it's not as it appears in the log.